# Not able to connect MySQL with Sails js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I am using sails latest version(0.10.*), I am trying to connect mysql data base, but its throwing following error.

> info: Starting app...
>   error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
>   error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
>   : Query inactivity timeout
>      at Query. >(/home/pavan/pavanwork/development/plotstoday/node_modules/sails->mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:154:17)
>      at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>      at Query.emit (events.js:166:7)
>      at Query._onTimeout >(/home/pavan/pavanwork/development/plotstoday/node_modules/sails->mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:116:8)
>      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:9

Configuration:

config/connection.js

```
  mysqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'vtiger',
    database: 'plotstoday'
  },
```

config/model.js

```
module.exports.models = {
 connection: 'mysqlServer',
  migrate: 'alter'

};
```

config/env/development.js

```
models: {
     //connection: 'localMongo'
     connection: 'mysqlServer'
   }
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Installed both sails-mysql adapter and node-mysql adapter.

I even tried  giving host:127.0.0.1.

Mysql is working fine from command-line, I tried the suggestion given

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sails.* TO 'homestead'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

(Reference : [Sails can not connect to mySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406734/sails-can-not-connect-to-mysql))

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with node(v4.2.0) and mysql. I was using node(v4.2.0), the above issue was coming. I upgraded to node v4.2.1, the above mysql timeout issue is resolved, and everything seems to be working